# How do I design a contacts database and store multiple line items per user?

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

I want to create a small invoicing application. My first step is creating a database with two tables where each client can have multiple addresses and phone numbers.

I think its safe to assume here that I am dealing with a `one to many` relationship. But how should I design the tables and fields so they can store multiple addresses and phone numbers per user? By multiple I also mean indeterminate since so I can't just have x no of columns in my table. Off Hand, here is what I was thinking:

```
Clients
- Id
- Notes

CONTACTS
- id
- client_id
- address
- phone number
```

Now I am trying to avoid a third join table like this:

```
Clients_Contacts
- id
- client_id
- contact id
```

because I still want a one to many and not `many to many` relationship between `contacts` and `clients`. Is there something wrong with the way I am thinking about this? Can someone please help me design this database and show me what a sample query querying multiple addresses would look like.

Comment: A Person and an Address is actually a Many-To-Many relationship, seeing as many people can live at an address and a person can have many addresses.

Comment: These are clients and belong to separate institutions. So the many-to-many relationship does not apply in this case. One client can have multiple addresses. Multiple addresses belong to one client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you nead a join table?

I would have

```
Client
- ID (PK, FK of Contact)
- Notes

Contact
- ID (PK)
- client_id
- address
- phone_number
```

Then just set the ID of the client to be the value of client_id within the contact information.

This way, multiple Contact records can have the same client_id.

Comment: but wouldn't that leave empty column fields or worse duplicates when doing inserts?

Comment: Where would there be empty column fields?

Comment: in the name and phone no columns?

Comment: Sorry @Amit, you have lost me a bit. If you have the fields nullable then of course you could have blanks, but I don't see how that is relevant to the original question.

Comment: the contacts table would have other fields like phone and primary contact etc. So if I kept adding rows of address data to the table, would't that leave those fields empty?

Comment: Well...yes obviously. The alternative would be a seperate table for each type of data you want, ie. one for addresses, one for phone numbers etc. Are you trying to say a client will only have one phone number and not multiple? And that it might have multiple addresses and only one primary contact etc? If so just move those fields to the Client table.

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea looks fine for your use-case (one to many). You'll only need the third join table if you want a many to many relationship, which you do not want.

A sample query to get all addresses from a specific client would be:

```
SELECT address FROM Contacts WHERE client_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to store multiple addresses and phone numbers per user (= client, I assume?). Your current model already supports this. Every client can have as many contacts as needed (each contact would have the client_id set to the client's id). Only if you want to assign a single contact (address/phone number) to multiple clients as well would you need the third table.